# function or a systemcall similar to "mountpoint" command in linux

Tags: c, linux

I wanted a function or a system call similar to mountpoint command Linux.
(this command will check if given directory is a mount point or not)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of an actual syscall that would do that, but what you can do is compare the device numbers of the directory that you want to check and its parent. That can be done with `stat`. Example code (error checking omitted) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  struct stat mp, mp_parent;
  stat("/boot", &mp);
  stat("/boot/..", &mp_parent);

  if (mp.st_dev != mp_parent.st_dev)
    printf("/boot is a mount point.\n");
  else
    printf("/boot is not a mount point.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how will comparing the device numbers answer my question?

Comment: If the device numbers aren't equal, the given path is a mount point. I don't really see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The need for functions like this is usually (though not *always*) a red flag that you're not embracing the abstractions of the system...and you should reconsider whatever-it-is-you're-doing.  If there is some choice you're making in your software based on whether something is a mountpoint...consider making that alternative behavior a parameter which can be controlled via scripting.  People can parameterize your program to adopt that behavior via using the native mountpoint command, or whatever else.

With that disclaimer aside, here's an implementation of `mountpoint.c`:

https://fossies.org/linux/sysvinit/src/mountpoint.c

...and a reference on "testing the type of a file"

http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_160.html

Comment: What if the question is simply "Is this directory a mount point" so you can say "if it is, unmount it" Not sure how one might abstract that.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own app to parse `/proc/mounts`. Then compare your path with paths from `/proc/mounts`. If they are equal then path is a mount point.